# Hash change not triggering ui-router change?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a link on my page (inside the scope of angular app 1) which changes the hash location

```
/app/#/location
```

I have another angular app (2) which is not reacting to the hash location change in the way I expect it to (ie by firing locationChangeStart, and changing state).  I don't fully understand why.  Anybody can explain this to me?

Edit 1: yes, there are two angular apps on the page, of different angular versions, both bootstrapped (sigh, don't ask).  The ui-router configuration looks like this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(($injector) => {
    let $state = $injector.get("$state");

    [... snip ...]

    $state.go('list');
});

// Now set up the states
$stateProvider
    .state('messaging', {
        url: "/messaging/{param}",
        templateUrl: "messaging.html",
        controller: 'MessagingController'
    })
    .state('list', {
        url: "/list",
        templateUrl: "list.html",
        controller: 'ListController'
    });
```

Nothing really too fancy here, and before anybody asks, yes, I do need to check on a state in the otherwise.

The bootstrapping looks like this:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.element(document.getElementById('app-bootstrap')).prepend('<div ui-view></div>');
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app-bootstrap'), ['app']);
});
```

Edit 2: this seems like it may be not an angular-related issue at all, as using the window 'hashchange' event directly doesn't seem to fire either; I've confirmed that window.onhashchange is the correct function.

(angular 1.4.7)

Comment: Are you bootstrapping either angular app?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to suggest that you have two angular applications on a single page.  Because this isn't a standard or recommended configuration, you will need to provide more detailed information than normal when requesting troubleshooting assistance.

Comment: Thanks, have added more info.